# DataList keep displaying previously loaded datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, datalist

I have a catalog function whereby user can filter their selection by clicking radiobutton. For example, by selecting the Dining radiobutton, all packages related to dining would appear.

And i using DataList1.Items.Count method to count the number search result.  I had implement this method in the page_load, however the value of the number of datalist keep displaying previously loaded datalist.

Here is my code :

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        DataList1.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource3";
        Label1.Text = DataList1.Items.Count.ToString(); 
    }


    private SqlDataReader getReader()
    {
        //get connection string from web.config
        string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ASPNETDBConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

        string strCommandText = "SELECT CategoryID, CatName  from Category";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);
        myConnect.Open();

        //DataList1.DataSource = reader; 

        DataList1.DataBind();

        // CommandBehavior.CloseConnection will automatically close connection
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        return reader;
    }

    protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        DataList1.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1";


        if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            Session["catID"] = 1;

        }
        else if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            Session["catID"] = 2;

        }
        else if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            Session["catID"] = 3; 

        }
        else if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex == 3)
        {
            Session["catID"] = 4;

        }
        else if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex == 4)
        {
            Session["catID"] = 5;

        }

        else
        {
            Session["catID"] = 8;

        }

    }
```

I had tried to place the Item.Count in other places of this code, but same problem persist..

Answer (score 0):

```
 Try this,
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
 {  
     if(!Page.IsPostBack) 
     {           
         DataList1.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource3";
         Label1.Text = DataList1.Items.Count.ToString();   
     } 
 }
```